# Do our scriptures give way to reduce or cross over Prarabdha Karma?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, karma, bhakti

It is stated that *Prarabdha Karma* is the one which the person has to undergo without a doubt and cannot be changed unlike other Karma-s which can be changed.

But do we have a way to cross or completely eliminate Prarabdha Karma? What does devotional path say about this? Do we have proper reference by which we can alter or eliminate this Karma?

The reason why I'm asking this question is - it were the same scriptures which said that it's difficult to remove one's Karma which is carried over many births but in "Bhagavad Gita", Krishna conveyed *Isvara Gyana* burns your Karmas to Ashes. So, is the *Brahma Gyana* the only way to overcome Prarabdha Karma?

Strongly related: [Does praying to God help attain that which is not present in our destiny](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24022)

Comment: Intensity of Prarabdha Karma can be reduced to a large extent through prayers. "One has to suffer the consequences of one’s deeds. But by repeating the Name of God, you can lessen its intensity. If you were destined to have a wound as wide as a ploughshare, you will get a pin-prick at least. The effect of Karma can be counteracted to a great extent by Japa and austerities." - Sarada Devi

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria but if we follow path of Moksha, Brahma Gyana path - is it possible to burn that Karma too? For Gyana, we need Karmas to be burnt right?

Comment: As per Ekadashi fast's kathaa, Ekadashi vrata is use to wash away all our sins. It washes not only current birth's sin but previous birth's sins too. For example the last Ekadashi that passed (Jaya or Aja Ekadashi) is specially known to remove sins of our past births. It(Jaya) remove our prev. birth sin so that we can get joy in current birth(coz we are facing grief in this birth coz of prev. birth's sin). So basically Ekadashi vrata is sin removal vrata and grants moksha. It is one of the easiest way of getting moksha. It fills life with joy and devotion.

Comment: Prarabdha Karma is faced even by Jivanmuktas (God realized), only intensity can be reduced. After realization, sanchita karma is burnt by the fire of knowledge and generation of Agami Karma is also prevented.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria I want to know then when Prarabdha Karma ends? How it can be stoppes from generation?

Comment: After God realization, the current birth is last and so is Prarabdha Karma. As long as God is not realized, there will be Prarabdha Karma.

Comment: @YDS does changing the destiny = changing Prarabdha Karma?

Comment: You don't want it to be reopened? Some users thought that it shd be closed that's why it got closed. Now some other users thought it shd be reopened. So five of them cast their reopen votes and it is reopened. @AkshayKumarS

Comment: There are 3 types of karma. 1) Sanchit, 2) Kriyamana, 3) Prarabdha.... No. 1 is accumulated over past so many births and present life, which can be burnt by sadhana. No. 3 is defined as "no.1 converted or ripened into no. 3". It can't be done away in short cut. We have to calmly suffer it; but yes, we may not feel its pinch as much. Bcoz if our mind would be attached with god through sadhana. (unlike somebody said that "its intensity would be reduced"). I would try to find scriptural ref. Don't remember where. So posting it as comment.

Comment: @YDS- is that how Markendaya could have changed his destiny?

Comment: @AkshayKumarS yeah...