# Can you change your long-term Bhaagya / Destiny / Future?

Tags: scripture, astrology

I think many of us have heard of this statement

> भाग्यं फलति सर्वत्र, न च विद्या, न च पौरुषं or Bhagyam phalati sarvatra, na cha vidyaa, na cha paurusham

Which basically means that knowledge and masculine courage/being energetic are useless as everything is based on your Bhaagya / Destiny. **Is this based on any sacred scripture?**

I have heard that you can easily change your long-term destiny by performing some austerities. In fact, even weak and destructive planets can be changed.

**Which view is correct according to different scriptures?**

Comment: Markandeya Muni was destined to die at 16. We all know what transpired then and how he was blessed to live even after the Kalpanta Pralaya.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does praying to God help attain that which is not present in our destiny](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24022/does-praying-to-god-help-attain-that-which-is-not-present-in-our-destiny)

Comment: No these are stories of gods themselves talking and intervening... which never happens in life... unless maybe youre an extreme sadhak of shiva or shakti who has done many many years of sadna

Comment: @R.Kaushik Do you require an exact jyotish answer, which tells you what part of destiny you can change and what you can't?

Comment: @Agni Yes please! But it doesn't just have to be from Jyotish shastr... can be from any other text containing Jyotish like Puraan or Tantra sruti