# Is there a way in Hinduism to get blessed with something that is not in one's destiny?

Tags: karma, desire, destiny

For example, if one is destined to be childless, can he/she still have a child?

Or if one is destined to be poor, can he/she become wealthy?

If there is a way / solution to be blessed with something that one desires that is not in one's destiny or prarabdha, what is it? Is it through pooja and anusthan, or penance? Please provide the details. Is this doable in the kaliyuga? Thank you.

Comment: The Lord is said to be: यस्य स्मरणमात्रेण जन्मसंसारबन्धनात् ।
विमुच्यते नमस्तस्मै विष्णवे प्रभविष्णवे ॥V.S. ॥ and further, भाविउ मेटि सकहिं त्रिपुरारी ॥RM 1.1.70॥ . Although, one cannot ever be fully absolved off their karmas (they'll have to sow what they reap), however, *īśvara* is called *Hari* & *Hara*. They snatch away (हर) the bad things from their devotees. They can definitely absorb one's saṃtāpa (grief) and act as umbrella in a heavy pourdown.

Comment: Yes, but very rare..like son was not in Harishchandra's destiny but he got son..long life was not in Markendya's, destiny but he got very long life..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does praying to God help attain that which is not present in our destiny](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/24022/does-praying-to-god-help-attain-that-which-is-not-present-in-our-destiny)

Comment: No, everything is predestined even a blessing, struggle, luck, time of death etc., which can be studied, decoded, and predicted through understanding one's encoded planetary Vedic horoscope. In reality, free will is a sham. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prarabdha_karma

Comment: @Vivikta- When does God snatch away the grief of a suffering human, and how can one get his mercy?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. For example, the atmadeva incident in [Srimad Bhagavatha](https://srimadbhagavata.wordpress.com/2009/09/08/srimad-bhagavatha-mahatmyam-story-of-atma-deva/) illustrates this.

> On the banks of river Tungabhadra, lived a well learned person by name
> Atmadeva. He was good natured person, while on the contrary, his wife,
> Dunduli always liked to talk about others and cause chaos in other
> families. The fact that he was not blessed with a child made Atmadeva
> a very sad man.
>
> Atmadeva lived with a ray of hope that someday he will be blessed with
> a child. However, as years passed by, his hopes started to diminish
> and one day unable to control his emotions, set out of the house. He
> didn’t know where he was going and finally reached a jungle.. In the
> jungle was a great Sadhu who was in meditation. His eyes caught sight
> of Atmadeva and seeing him in a very depressed state walked towards
> him and enquired about him. After hearing his desire to be blessed
> with a child, he started to perceive if he was fortunate to have a
> child in that birth.
>
> The Sadhu could foresee that Atmadeva was destined with no progeny not
> only in his present birth but also in all his future births. Hearing
> this from the sage’s mouth, Atmadeva broke down and the sage was
> unable to console him.
>
> Seeing Atmadeva in that state, the sage gave Atmadeva a fruit and
> ordained that he would be blessed with progeny if his wife ate the
> fruit. Mahans have divine powers that they can even change the fate of
> a person as seen above. **Atmadeva was destined to not have a child in
> all his births, but the blessings of a Sadhu changed his fate.**

Similarly, the [destiny of Markandeya](https://indiathedestiny.com/religion/sage-markandeya-story/) was changed by Lord Shiva.

But one should also understand these are exceptions and not the rule. For a more detailed fate vs freewill debate, please see the answers of [the Sringeri pontiff.](https://www.advaita-vedanta.org/articles/The_Riddle_of_Fate_and_Free.htm).

Comment: I think the destiny really cannot be changed. But instead destiny of a person can be miscalculated, so it seems like his or her destiny has changed. Even great people can only see partial tendencies of a person's destiny. Not the actual destiny. Hence forth predictions can be changed. Because it is almost impossible to know one's destiny. For example Markandeya Rishi was always destined to be a Chiranjeevi.

Comment: Thank you for your response.